# Getting FS0035 => Construct is deprecated

Tags: f#, compiler-errors, deprecated, fsyacc, fslex

In a fsyacc based project, I have this line:

```
type 'a cucomment = string
```

This is the full error description I'm getting:

> CALast.fs(117,9): error FS0035: This construct is deprecated:  This
>   type abbreviation has one or more declared type parameters that do not
>   appear in the type being abbreviated. Type abbreviations must use all
>   declared  type parameters in the type being abbreviated. Consider
>   removing one or more  type parameters, or use a concrete type
>   definition that wraps an underlying  type, such as 'type C<'a> = C of
>   ...'.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Just for people visiting this and wondering about the syntax, this is alternative syntax for the more common `type cucomment<'a> = string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# no longer allows type aliases that add generic type parameters to a type without declaring a new type. If you want to define a generic type that wraps some other type, you have to use some constructor. For example, you can use single-case discriminated union:

```
type 'a Cucomment = CC of string
```

Unfortunately, this means that you'd have to change all code that uses the type to unwrap the value using pattern matching or by adding `Value` member to the type.

The only case where generic type aliases are allowed is when you declare a version of type with units of measure, which requires a special attribute. However, this is probably not going to work for you (because units behave quite differently):

```
[<MeasureAnnotatedAbbreviation>]
type 'a Cucomment = string
```

If this is in some code generated by **fsyacc**, then that's a bug in fsyacc that should be fixed (I think this was quite recent change). In that case, report it to `fsbugs` at `microsoft` dot `com`.